# Why does async / await function run twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, sequelize.js

I'm working with `express` and `node.js` application. I have a regular router, which:

- finds `myID` in `DB`,
- if `myID` exists it tries to `addVisit()`
- if error occures (may such table doesn't exist) it catches the error, creates the new table and `addVisit()` to it.

The router code is below:

```
    router.get('/:myId', errorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.params.myId + ' This is myID Params!');

    const Domain = DomainModel(db, Sequelize);
    const Click = ClickModel(db, `${req.params.myId}_clicks`, Sequelize);

    try {
        let row = await Domain.findOne({ where: { myId: req.params.myId } });

        console.log(row.myId + ' This is myID from DB');

        if (row.myId) {
            try {
                await addVisit(Click, req);
                res.sendStatus(200);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(`This error fires!`);
                if (err.message !== `Validation error`) {
                    try {
                        await db.sync();
                        await addVisit(Click, req);
                        res.sendStatus(200);
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.sendStatus(400);
                    }
                } else {
                    res.sendStatus(400);
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log(`No such myId in use`);
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

But the code runs twice! My `console.log()` shows:

```
1. ==> 1231231231 This is myID Params!
2. ==> 1231231231 This is myID from DB
3. ==> This error fires!
4. ==> favicon.ico This is myID Params!
5. ==> TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of null
```

If I comment this part of code it runs only one time!

```
// if (err.message !== `Validation error`) {
//    try {
//        await db.sync();
//        await addVisit(Click, req);
//        res.sendStatus(200);
//    } catch (err) {
//        console.log(err);
//        res.sendStatus(400);
//    }
// } else {
//    res.sendStatus(400);
// }
```

This is the only place where I use `console.log()`! This is the simple sample project in which I able to reproduce the behavior. So why does the code runs twice and WHY my params.myID became favicon.ico?

Comment: Because your browser is sending two requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you open a webpage, there is a small icon in the upper left corner of the tab, containing the logo of the page. That icon gets loaded from `theserver/favicon.ico`, if that returns an error the icon stays empty, otherwise the photo returned by that is used as the icon. There are other such reserved files, such as `norobots.txt` and `manifest.json`. Therefore it is a bad idea to have the variable url part at the main level. This one:

```
 router.get('/:myId'
```

catches everything. Instead you should move it to a subpath:

```
 router.get('/id/:myId'
```

Comment: OMG! How much time I lose with this (( Thank you for explanation. Now it works like it should!

Answer (score 2):

Because with route param `/:myId` you will serve `/favicon` request too. So those are the 2 requests.

Comment: What should I do to serv only one request?

Comment: It is bad a practice to use param in the first place. Because you will serve every request. You should always start your route with static part. `/static-part/:my-param` Or you can validate your url/param with some RegExp, but that is very expensive.